# JAVA: Circles are bound to one position in imageview when zooming in/out

Tags: java, javafx, geometry, zooming

So I'm trying to zoom and pan an image in an image view, and right now it is zooming and panning perfectly. The problem I am facing is I have circles added on top of the image and whenever I zoom in/out, they always remain in the same position of the imageview whereas the image is zooming in/out properly. What I want to happen is for the circles to be tied to the image such that they zoom in/out and pan along with the image as one unit.

I found the code for zoom/pan from another forum/post and adjusted it so that it works for my code. And it does. Inside the setImageI() method, I tried to fix the issue which I have commented out but doesn't work.

```
 //this function displays nodes(circles) and edges(lines)

 public void displayAllNodes() {
    ...

    mapImgPane.getChildren().remove(1, mapImgPane.getChildren().size());
    double mapX = findPathImgView.getLayoutX();
    double mapY = findPathImgView.getLayoutY();

    final double[] orgSceneX = new double[1];
    final double[] orgSceneY = new double[1];

    for (Node n : nodes) {
        orgSceneX[0] = -1;
        orgSceneY[0] = -1;
        Circle circle = new Circle();

        double mapScale = findPathImgView.getImage().getWidth() / findPathImgView.getFitWidth();
        circle.setCenterX(mapX + n.getX() / mapScale);
        circle.setCenterY(mapY + n.getY() / mapScale);
        circle.setRadius(3.0);
        circle.setFill(black);
        mapImgPane.getChildren().add(circle);
        nodeCircles.put(n.getID(), circle);
    }
    for (Edge e : edges) {
        if (!(nodeCircles.containsKey(e.getStartNode()) && nodeCircles.containsKey(e.getEndNode()))) {
            // this edge is not on this floor so we do not draw it
        } else {
            Line line = new Line();
            line.startXProperty().bind(nodeCircles.get(e.getStartNode()).centerXProperty());
            line.startYProperty().bind(nodeCircles.get(e.getStartNode()).centerYProperty());
            line.endXProperty().bind(nodeCircles.get(e.getEndNode()).centerXProperty());
            line.endYProperty().bind(nodeCircles.get(e.getEndNode()).centerYProperty());
            line.setStroke(black);
            mapImgPane.getChildren().add(line);
        }
    }

    if (findLocationNodeID != null && nodeCircles.containsKey(findLocationNodeID)) {
        Circle foundNode = nodeCircles.get(findLocationNodeID);

        foundNode.setRadius(6.0);
        foundNode.setFill(Color.ORANGERED);
        foundNode.toFront();

        ScaleTransition st = new ScaleTransition(Duration.millis(2000), foundNode);
        st.setByX(1.2);
        st.setByY(1.2);
        st.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        st.setAutoReverse(true);
        st.play();
    }
 }

 //this function sets the image to the imageview, calls the zoom function setImageI() to add zoom/pan functionality to imageview
 public void updateFloorImg(String floor) {
    ...

    if (imageCache.containsKey(floorURL)) {
        findPathImgView.setImage(imageCache.get(floorURL));
        setImageI(imageCache.get(floorURL));
    } else {
        Image newImage = new Image(String.valueOf(getClass().getResource("/img/" + floorURL)));
        imageCache.put(floorURL, newImage);
        findPathImgView.setImage(newImage);
        setImageI(newImage);
    }
    findPathImgView.fitWidthProperty().bind(mapImgPane.widthProperty());
 }

 //this function and subsequent functions I found from a post enables zoom/pan functionality
 private void setImageI(Image image) {

    double width = findPathImgView.getImage().getWidth();
    double height = findPathImgView.getImage().getHeight();

    findPathImgView.setPreserveRatio(true);
    reset(findPathImgView, width, height);

    ObjectProperty<Point2D> mouseDown = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    findPathImgView.setOnMousePressed(e -> {

        Point2D mousePress = imageViewToImage(findPathImgView, new Point2D(e.getX(), e.getY()));
        mouseDown.set(mousePress);
    });

    findPathImgView.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
        Point2D dragPoint = imageViewToImage(findPathImgView, new Point2D(e.getX(), e.getY()));
        shift(findPathImgView, dragPoint.subtract(mouseDown.get()));
        mouseDown.set(imageViewToImage(findPathImgView, new Point2D(e.getX(), e.getY())));
    });

    findPathImgView.setOnScroll(e -> {
        double delta = e.getDeltaY();
        Rectangle2D viewport = findPathImgView.getViewport();

        double scale = clamp(Math.pow(1.01, delta),

                // don't scale so we're zoomed in to fewer than MIN_PIXELS (1000px) in any direction:
                Math.min(MIN_PIXELS / viewport.getWidth(), MIN_PIXELS / viewport.getHeight()),

                // don't scale so that we're bigger than image dimensions:
                Math.max(width / viewport.getWidth(), height / viewport.getHeight())

        );

        currentZoomLevel /= scale;

        Point2D mouse = imageViewToImage(findPathImgView, new Point2D(e.getX(), e.getY()));

        double newWidth = viewport.getWidth() * scale;
        double newHeight = viewport.getHeight() * scale;

        // To keep the visual point under the mouse from moving, we need
        // (x - newViewportMinX) / (x - currentViewportMinX) = scale
        // where x is the mouse X coordinate in the image

        // solving this for newViewportMinX gives

        // newViewportMinX = x - (x - currentViewportMinX) * scale

        // we then clamp this value so the image never scrolls out
        // of the imageview:

        double newMinX = clamp(mouse.getX() - (mouse.getX() - viewport.getMinX()) * scale,
                0, width - newWidth);
        double newMinY = clamp(mouse.getY() - (mouse.getY() - viewport.getMinY()) * scale,
                0, height - newHeight);

        findPathImgView.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(newMinX, newMinY, newWidth, newHeight));

        // let's do some math to move and scale the nodes

       double mapScale = findPathImgView.getImage().getWidth() / findPathImgView.getFitWidth();

        /*** HERE I included stuff for the circles ***/
        for (Circle c : nodeCircles.values()) {
            c.setScaleX(currentZoomLevel);
            c.setScaleY(currentZoomLevel);


                 /*** This is how I tried to fix it but doesn't really work. ***/
 //                if (mouse.getX() / mapScale > c.getCenterX()) {
 //                    c.setCenterX(c.getCenterX() - Math.abs(c.getCenterX() - mouse.getX() / mapScale) * scale);
 //                } else {
 //                    c.setCenterX(c.getCenterX() + Math.abs(c.getCenterX() - mouse.getX() / mapScale) * scale);
 //                }


 //                c.setCenterX(c.getCenterX() + (scale * mouse.getX()));
 //                c.setCenterY(c.getCenterY() + (scale * mouse.getY()));
 //                c.scaleXProperty().setValue(currentZoomLevel);
 //                c.scaleYProperty().setValue(currentZoomLevel);
        }


    });

    findPathImgView.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
        if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
            reset(findPathImgView, width, height);
        }
    });

    findPathImgView.setPreserveRatio(true);


    findPathImgView.fitWidthProperty().bind(mapImgPane.widthProperty());
    findPathImgView.fitHeightProperty().bind(mapImgPane.heightProperty());
 }

 // reset to the top left:
 private void reset(ImageView imageView, double width, double height) {
    imageView.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(0, 0, width, height));
    currentZoomLevel = 1;
 }

 // shift the viewport of the imageView by the specified delta, clamping so
 // the viewport does not move off the actual image:
 private void shift(ImageView imageView, Point2D delta) {
    Rectangle2D viewport = imageView.getViewport();

    double width = imageView.getImage().getWidth() ;
    double height = imageView.getImage().getHeight() ;

    double maxX = width - viewport.getWidth();
    double maxY = height - viewport.getHeight();

    double minX = clamp(viewport.getMinX() - delta.getX(), 0, maxX);
    double minY = clamp(viewport.getMinY() - delta.getY(), 0, maxY);

    imageView.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(minX, minY, viewport.getWidth(), viewport.getHeight()));
 }

 private double clamp(double value, double min, double max) {

    if (value < min)
        return min;
    if (value > max)
        return max;
    return value;
 }

 // convert mouse coordinates in the imageView to coordinates in the actual image:
 private Point2D imageViewToImage(ImageView imageView, Point2D imageViewCoordinates) {
    double xProportion = imageViewCoordinates.getX() / imageView.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth();
    double yProportion = imageViewCoordinates.getY() / imageView.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight();

    Rectangle2D viewport = imageView.getViewport();
    return new Point2D(
            viewport.getMinX() + xProportion * viewport.getWidth(),
            viewport.getMinY() + yProportion * viewport.getHeight());
 }

 private ImageView setImageView(Image image) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
    imageView.setImage(image);

    double w;
    double h;

    double ratioX = imageView.getFitWidth() / imageView.getImage().getWidth();
    double ratioY = imageView.getFitHeight() / imageView.getImage().getHeight();

    double reducCoeff;
    if(ratioX >= ratioY) {
        reducCoeff = ratioY;
    } else {
        reducCoeff = ratioX;
    }

    w = imageView.getImage().getWidth() * reducCoeff;
    h = imageView.getImage().getHeight() * reducCoeff;

    imageView.setX((imageView.getFitWidth() - w) / 2);
    imageView.setY((imageView.getFitHeight() - h) / 2);

    return imageView;
 }
```

I want the circles to move/zoom/pan relative to the image and not stay fixed to one position of the view. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using scene builder add methods on your circle that function according to what happens to the image. Like when u zoom on it make the circle zoom as well etc. It can be done by just coding it with basic JavaFx but it would be better to visualize it